# How to resize a responsive list from three columns to one (using responsivegridsystem.com)

Tags: responsive-design

I am using [www.responsivegridsystem.com](http://www.responsivegridsystem.com) for my columns and here is what I've come up with: [ux.stoicdigital.com/#intro-message](http://ux.stoicdigital.com/#intro-message).

I'd like the list to work like this one: http://doyouimpress.com/#uses-list

The biggest problems are that, above a certain amount of px (can't remember exact), the three column grid is centered, but doesn't LOOK centered due to cell widths, etc. and that below that amount of px (when list is in one-column mode), the off-center problem is even worse.

Again, I realize that this has to do with cell widths, etc. but I can't figure out where to make the changes I need to do the following at both sizes:

1. Align text and bullets left
2. Center the list itself on the page

Any advice would be appreciated. Would especially appreciate any details you can give re: changes to make to CSS.

PS: If there is another way to achieve this outside of Responsive Grid System, I'm open to that too.

Answer (score 0):

The text doesn't look centered because it isn't. The container div is centered, but since you align the text to the left its all scewed to the left, just like it'd be scewed to the right if you aligned the text to the right.

You could align the text to the middle, but then your checkbox icons wouldn't be lined up. If you want the text to be centered but still have the icons lined up you need to attach the icons so something else but the text. You could display them as [pseudo-elements](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/) to the `<li>`, but the drawback is that there would be varying amounts of space between the text and the icons.

What I'm coming at is basically that you can't center the columns this way (as long as you don't make sure that the text in each `<li>` is equally wide) - however you can fake it and that's what they do on that site you're referring to.

To fake it, simply give each column div a unique class name (or target them with [`:nth-child`](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)), then move each column manually to make it look like the content is centered. You could give them different `width`-values (this is what they do in your example), different `padding`-values or similar. That's entirely up to you.

As for the one-column layout, do something similar where you add a `padding`-value to push them closer to the center, but obviously use the same value for all column divs.

Comment: Thanks, @Nils. I'll give this a try and report back. Cheers!

Comment: Tried it, and realized that I have no idea how to "give each column div a unique class name". Can you give any examples of the CSS required to pull this off?

Comment: I think you know how to do it, I probably just phrased myself in a weird way. 

You have three `divs` with the class name `span_1_of_3`, wrapping the list items you want to center. Give all of these `divs` and additional class name so you can target them individually and give them different widths. That's all. :-)

Comment: I did all that you suggested. Definitely helped to target the column divs with unique class names.

Comment: Currently I'm adding a margin-left: 30% to try to "center" the first div of the one-column list, but I cannot figure out why the 30% doesn't "flex" as I resize the window. It seems to stay static. Any ideas? Almost there... THANKS!

Comment: I made all the changes that @NilsKaspersson suggested, and I am still having trouble with the alignment problem. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance!